# How do you assert when testing a Node module that uses promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, q, sinon

I have a Node controller “simpleController” which has a dependency on an instance of “DataAccess”. The controller calls the function “getData” on the instance of “DataAccess” and has a promise returned to it. If the promise is then rejected, the controller should return a status of 500.

I would like to write a test on “simpleController” but mock the instance of “DataAccess” so I can return a failed promise and assert the “simpleController” behaviour is as expected.

I have attempted to write a unit test to perform this but the test times out.

```
(function (simpleController) {

    var DataAccess = require('./DataAccess');

    var dataAccessInstance;

    simpleController.init = function (dataSource) {
        dataAccessInstance = new DataAccess(dataSource);
    };

    simpleController.setMockDependencies = function (mockDataAccessInstance) {
        dataAccessInstance = mockDataAccessInstance;
    };

    simpleController.performAction = function (req, res) {

        var entityId = req.query.id;

        dataAccessInstance.getData(entityId)
            .then(function (data){
                res.status(200).json(data);
            },
            function (err) {
                res.status(200).json(err);
            });
    }

})(module.exports);



/* global describe, it */
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var Q = require('q');
var DataAccess = require('../lib/temp/DataAccess');

describe('Simple Controller Tests', function () {

    var simpleController;
    var dataAccess;

    beforeEach(function (done) {

        simpleController = require('../lib/temp/simpleController');

        var dataSource = 'dummy';
        dataAccess = new DataAccess(dataSource);

        done();
    });


    it('should return status of 500 if data access fails', function (done) {

        // Arrange
        var req = { query: { id: '12345678' } };
        var res = {};

        var deferred = Q.defer();

        var stub = sinon.stub(dataAccess, 'getData', function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        });

        simpleController.setMockDependencies(dataAccess);

        deferred.promise.fail(function () {

            // Assert
            assert.ok(stub.called);
            assert.equal(res.status, 500);

            done();

        });

        // Act
        simpleController.performAction(req, res);

        deferred.reject();
    });

});



(function () {

    function DataAccess(dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    DataAccess.prototype.getData = function (entityId) {
        throw new Error('Not implemented');
    };

    module.exports = DataAccess;
})();
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are running into,as far as I can tell, is that you have supplied failure handlers for your promise in two places. Once by calling deferred.promise.fail in your test, and once by passing a second argument to dataAccessInstance.getData(entityId).then in your controller. The one in your controller is presumably replacing the one you added in your test. I would recommend removing this code (it isn't really doing anything useful):

```
deferred.promise.fail(function () {

        // Assert
        assert.ok(stub.called);
        assert.equal(res.status, 500);

        done();

    });
```

and instead of using an empty object for res in your test, add a status method, and do your assertion there:

```
it('should return status of 500 if data access fails', function (done) {

    // Arrange
    var req = { query: { id: '12345678' } };
    var res = {};

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var stub = sinon.stub(dataAccess, 'getData', function() {
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    simpleController.setMockDependencies(dataAccess);

    res.status = function (status) {

        // Assert
        assert.ok(stub.called);
        assert.equal(status, 500);

        done();

    };

    // Act
    simpleController.performAction(req, res);

    deferred.reject();
});
```

Also, note that in your controller you are using 200 for both success and failure, I think you meant to use 500 for failure. Finally, you should add .done() at the end of your promise chain:

```
dataAccessInstance.getData(entityId)
       .then(function (data){
           res.status(200).json(data);
       },
       function (err) {
           res.status(500).json(err);
       })
       .done();
```

(see http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/the-end). This will avoid a timeout in the case your test fails.

Comment: Nope, `fail` handlers do not replace each other.

Comment: I stand corrected with respect to my comments regarding the cause of the problem. In the original code, there is an attempt to call res.status() on a res object that has no res method defined. The the lack of .done() at the end of the promise chain obscured this problem, since it was causing a timeout. When the .done() is added, we would have seen:TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'status'